# Unable to identify the perticular array of of my json using GSON. and add them to a list

Tags: android, json, gson, jsonparser

Main Activity Code fragment ... i have tried responce.getObject but it didnot work...

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest( Request.Method.GET,
               URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        if (response == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't fetch the menu! Pleas try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        List<Person> persons = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Person>>() {
                        }.getType());

                        // adding persons to cart list
                        cartList.clear();
                        cartList.addAll(persons);
```

Myjson file

```
{
  "code": 1200,
  "message": "Data Retrieved",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Vangipurapu Venkata Sai Laxman",
      "skills": "Cricketer, Batsman",
      "image": "https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-4f5029c4319b41270f5643d461979645-c"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Himesh Reshammiya",
      "skills": "music director, singer, producer, lyricist, distributor and actor",
      "image": "https://starsunfolded-1ygkv60km.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Himesh-Reshammiya-nasal-singing.jpg"
    }
]
}
```

How to identify the object "data" and access all the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you cannot use *JsonArrayRequest* in this case. This is because your *Myjson file* does not have an array at root but rather an object.You should be using *JsonObjectRequest* instead.

So this is how your code should look:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if (response == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't fetch the menu! Pleas try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    Person persons = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<Person>() {
                    }.getType());

                    // adding persons to cart list
                    cartList.clear();
                    cartList.add(persons);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("error", error.toString());
                }
    });
```

Remember to change

```
 List<Person> persons = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Person>>() {
                    }.getType());
```

to

```
Person persons = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<Person>() {
                }.getType());
```

This is because of the same reason as above: you are getting a *json object* not a *json array*.

Now, the way *Gson* works is that it needs a class to 'map' the received *Json* to. Therefore you have to create a class. Looking at your Json, this is simple implementation of your *Person* class.

```
public class Person {
private int code;
private String message;
private List<Data> data;

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public List<Data> getData() {
    return data;
}

public class Data {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String skills;
    private String image;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}}
```

And this is how you access the data array and its objects.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cartList.size(); i++) {
                        for (Person.Data data : cartList.get(i).getData()) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Name: " + data.getName() + ", Skill: " + data.getSkills() + ", Image: " + data.getImage() + ", id: " + data.getId());
                        }
                    }
```

Here i am printing data in the Logcat. Make sure to do this in the onResponse() block.

And this is how the complete code looks like:

```
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if (response == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't fetch the menu! Pleas try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    Person persons = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<Person>() {
                    }.getType());

                    // adding persons to cart list
                    cartList.clear();
                    cartList.add(persons);

                    for (int i = 0; i < cartList.size(); i++) {
                        for (Person.Data data : cartList.get(i).getData()) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Name: " + data.getName() + ", Skill: " + data.getSkills() + ", Image: " + data.getImage() + ", id: " + data.getId());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("error", error.toString());
                }
    });

    requestQueue.add(request);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: WOho....You just saved my whole night..Thanks for your explanation :) one more thing.. can u pleasae give me a good link from where i can read more about jsonparsing and all these concepts...Thanks a lot

Comment: @satyajitdas You're welcome :) here are some links [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) and for Gson [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) . And can you please accept my answer, will be of great help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the entire JSON response, not just the "data" property. The GSON file used to parse it will probably look something like this:

```
public class MyJsonResponse {
    @SerializedName("code")
    private int code;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<Person> data;
}
```

Then you can get the data field from your parsed response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to convert you json response to POJO classes.
For your current response it would be like, It has  also implemented `Parcelable` below is the code:

`JsonResponse.java`

```
public class JsonResponse implements Parcelable
{

@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private Integer code;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;
public final static Parcelable.Creator<JsonResponse> CREATOR = new Creator<JsonResponse>() {


@SuppressWarnings({
"unchecked"
})
public JsonResponse createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
return new JsonResponse(in);
}

public JsonResponse[] newArray(int size) {
return (new JsonResponse[size]);
}

}
;

protected JsonResponse(Parcel in) {
this.code = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
this.message = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
in.readList(this.data, (com.heyoe_chat.model.Datum.class.getClassLoader()));
}

public JsonResponse() {
}

public Integer getCode() {
return code;
}

public void setCode(Integer code) {
this.code = code;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public List<Datum> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
this.data = data;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
dest.writeValue(code);
dest.writeValue(message);
dest.writeList(data);
}

public int describeContents() {
return 0;
}

}
```

`Datum.java` for objects in array.

```
public class Datum implements Parcelable
{

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("skills")
@Expose
private String skills;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;
public final static Parcelable.Creator<Datum> CREATOR = new Creator<Datum>() {


@SuppressWarnings({
"unchecked"
})
public Datum createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
return new Datum(in);
}

public Datum[] newArray(int size) {
return (new Datum[size]);
}

}
;

protected Datum(Parcel in) {
this.id = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
this.name = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
this.skills = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
this.image = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
}

public Datum() {
}

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getSkills() {
return skills;
}

public void setSkills(String skills) {
this.skills = skills;
}

public String getImage() {
return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
this.image = image;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
dest.writeValue(id);
dest.writeValue(name);
dest.writeValue(skills);
dest.writeValue(image);
}

public int describeContents() {
return 0;
}

}
```